# Display row by selected ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I started using PDO recently, earlier I used Mysql functions.. Now I am trying to get and display record by selected ID from the previous web page.
    firtly i use Connexion Class

```
Class Connexion {

private $host = "localhost";
private $user = "root";
private $pass = "";
private $dbname = "cvtheque";
private $dbh;
private $stmt;

public function __construct() {
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
    // Set options
    $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    );
    // Create a new PDO instanace
    try {
        $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
    }
    // Catch any errors
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Connexion Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function query($query) {
    $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
}

public function bind($param, $value, $type = null) {
    if (is_null($type)) {
        switch (true) {
            case is_int($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                break;
            case is_bool($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                break;
            case is_null($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                break;
            default:
                $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
        }
    }
    $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
}

public function execute() {
    return $this->stmt->execute();
}

public function resultset() {
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

public function single() {
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

public function rowCount() {
    return $this->stmt->rowCount();
}

public function lastInsertId() {
    return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
}

public function beginTransaction() {
    return $this->dbh->beginTransaction();
}

public function endTransaction() {
    return $this->dbh->commit();
}

public function cancelTransaction() {
    return $this->dbh->rollBack();
}

public function debugDumpParams() {
    return $this->stmt->debugDumpParams();
 }
}
```

i use these script to display items from database

```
<?php
$c = new Connexion();
$c->query("select * from annonce order by 'client' DESC Limit 20");
$rows = $c->resultset();  ?>
 <div class="Joblist" charset="UTF-8">
                <?php foreach($rows as $r) { ?>
        <p class="Title">
          <span class="Ref"></span>
          <a href="details.php?id=<?php echo($r['id_annonce']) ?>">
                <?php echo($r['poste']); ?></a></p>
        <p class="Date"><span class="Fright"><?php echo($r['type_contrat']); ?></span>
        <span><a href="http://www.maximus-it.com/job-search-result.php?sector=1#"  class="Sectorbtn"><?php echo($r['client']); ?></a></span></p>
        <p style="text-align:justify;"><?php echo tronque($r['desc_annonce'], 230);?></p>
        <p class="More"><a href="details.php?id=<?php echo($r['id_annonce']) ?>">Voir plus</a>       </p>
              <?php }?>
 </div>
```

then i use these method for select row by ID taken from the URL

```
 <?php
   require_once '../Model/Connexion.php';
   $c = new Connexion();
   if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
            $results = $c->query("select * from annonce where id=".$_GET['code']);
            $row = $c->single();
                             }
?>

 <div class="Content FCKeditor">
     <a style="float:right" href="javascript:history.go(-1);">back</a>

    <?php while($row) { ?>  
      <h1><?php echo($r['poste']); ?></h1>
          <div class="Jobdetails">
        <p class="Date"><span></span> | 
            <span><a href="job-details.php?id=792" class="Sectorbtn"><?php echo($r['client']); ?></a></span> | 
            <span><?php echo($r['type_contrat']); ?></span>
        </p>
            <?php echo($r['desc_annonce']); ?>
            <?php }?>
          </div>

 </div>
```

it shows  "Undefined variable: $row" on this line  , how can resolve this problem ?

Comment: As an aside, LIMIT without ORDER BY (or at least a GROUP BY) is pretty much meaningless.

Comment: Have a look at `$c->query("select * from annonce order by 'client' DESC Limit 20");` This column name shouldn't be in single quotes. Either none or backticks (or double quotes in ansi mode).

Comment: $_GET['code'] includes the '=' sign?

Comment: And in `$results = $c->query("select * from annonce limit 20 where id".$_GET['code']);` you forgot an equal sign. But you should use a prepared statement with a parameter. That's great and you would find this error at once.

Comment: The order of the clauses is `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... LIMIT`.

Comment: there is no problem in the second script, the problem derived from the third script

Comment: Your statement should be prepared with `SELECT * FROM annonce WHERE id = ? LIMIT 20;` Then you can bind the value of $_GET['code`] to this parameter. You could of course use a named parameter instead.

Comment: @SimonBerra Your query in the second script is not syntactically wrong, but I think it does something else as you expect, see [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e34a/2). Have a look at the error message for my second statement that's like yours in the third script.

Comment: @SimonBerra: As Marcos and I said before: there's an equal sign missing between `id` and `$_GET['code']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `single()` function is incorrect

```
public function single() {
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Should be

```
public function single() {
    $this->stmt->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

same applies for `resultset()`:

```
public function resultset() {
    $this->stmt->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

---

Most of these functions are one liner which is pointless except for getter and setter but it is not the case, you can create a function with the constructor logic if you need reusability

```
public function get_connexion() {
    return $this->dbh;
}
```

**php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    //require only when code is set
    require_once '../Model/Connexion.php';
    //create conn
    $db = new Connexion();
    $conn = $db->get_connexion();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('select * from annonce where id = ?');
    $stmt->execute(array($_GET['code']));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
}
?>
```

**HTML** (no loop since its single)

```
<div class="Content FCKeditor">
     <a style="float:right" href="javascript:history.go(-1);">back</a>
      <h1><?php echo($row['poste']); ?></h1>
          <div class="Jobdetails">
        <p class="Date"><span></span> | 
            <span><a href="job-details.php?id=792" class="Sectorbtn"><?php echo($row['client']); ?></a></span> | 
            <span><?php echo($row['type_contrat']); ?></span>
        </p>
            <?php echo($row['desc_annonce']); ?>
          </div>
 </div>
```

---

**Avoid Sql injection:**

```
<?php 
require_once '../Model/Connexion.php'; 
$c = new Connexion(); 
$c->query('select * from annonce where id_annonce= :id'); 
$c->bind(':id', $_GET['id']);
$r = $c->single(); 
?>
```

Comment: these functions are coorects i toke this code from http://culttt.com/2012/10/01/roll-your-own-pdo-php-class/

Comment: @SimonBerra have you tried my suggestion please try it

Comment: here is the code that works

<?php
require_once '../Model/Connexion.php';
$c = new Connexion();
$c->query("select * from annonce where id_annonce=".$_GET['id']);
$r = $c->single();
?>

Comment: What is different? Also avoid sql injection

Comment: comment on peut éviter SQL injection ?

Comment: @SimonBerra regarde la derniere parti de ma reponse?